# Want to use SSIS to get csv file with Null values into SQL Server DB table while preserving Nulls and maintaining floating point casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

Here is an example csv file:

Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4
1.0E+4,2.0E+3,3.1E-2,4.1E+4
NULL,1.0E-2,2.0E+1,3.2E-2

Using SSIS in Visual Studio, I want to get this file from csv format to a SQL Server DB table. I have a Data Flow Task which contains a Flat File Source and an ADO NET Destination. The SQL table has already been created with all columns cast as float. In the Flat File source I cast all columns as (DT_R4). An error is raised when I execute the package. The error is [Flat File Source [21]], data conversion failure for Col1. It is because I have a "Null" in the file. If instead of a Null I have an empty space, the SQL data table contains a "0" rather than a "Null." Is there anything I can put in place of "Null" in the csv file that SQL Server will interpret as Null and won't cause errors for SSIS? Please keep in mind that I actually have 100+ data files, each 500 MB big and each with 600+ columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived column component  - Create a DerivedCol1 as 
[Col1]=="Null"?  NULL(DT_R4):[Col1] and map it to the destination column. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that already because I had seen something similar in other posts. However, I am getting an error when I click OK in the Derived Column Transformation editor, actual it seems to be several errors. One of the errors is below: 
Error at Data Flow Task [Derived Column [27]]: The data types "DT_R4" and "DT_WSTR" are incompatible for binary operator "==". The operand types could not be implicitly cast into compatible types for the operation. To perform this operation, one or both operands need to be explicitly cast with a cast operator.

Comment: My current workaround is to use a search and replace program (TextCrawler) to replace all the Nulls in all my data files with a numeric code that will not show up in my normal data values (ie. 11111111). I then use the code with syntax you suggested and it works. I just figure that there has got to be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try
IsNull(col)?" ":col in derived column

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the technical error when you click **OK** you can see that it needs cast:

```
"null" == LOWER(myCol)  ? (DT_STR, 50, 1252) NULL(DT_STR, 50, 1252) : myCol
```

It's weird becase `NULL(DT_STR,50,1252)` should already return a **null** of that type.